# How to set a role in a Telegram group

Tags: telegram-messenger

I'd like to set a specific role to a person in telegram. It's like the "admin" role, for every message an admin has written in a group there is the note "admin" near the name. I'm one of the admins in a group and I'd like to call myself somehow differently than "admin". How to do that in Telegram desktop or the android app?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: u need to be full fledge admin (add more admins) and then u can hold on admin profile -> edit admin rights -> and find: custom title. I'm not sure if u can edit ur own title, or it possible by chat owner.

Comment: Almost got it. Could you please recall how exactly all those buttons I need to click are called? Kinda the whole path from the group info to the field with custom name editing